# reflection api give overloading on function's return type

Tags: java, reflection

I am using reflection APIs to do some queries on Java methods. Below is the code snippet to find out the return type of calling, say `new java.lang.StringBuilder().append('a')`:

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName("java.lang.StringBuilder");
Method[] mList = c.getMethods();

for (int i = 0; i < mList.length; i++) {
    if (mList[i].getName() == "append" 
          && mList[i].getParameterTypes().length == 1 
          && mList[i].getParameterTypes()[0].getCanonicalName() == "char") {
        System.out.println(mList[i]);
    }
}
```

Oddly, the output gives

> public java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder java.lang.StringBuilder.append(char)
>
> public java.lang.Appendable java.lang.StringBuilder.append(char) throws java.io.IOException
>
> public java.lang.StringBuilder java.lang.StringBuilder.append(char)

while the Java API Specification only gives `StringBuilder` as the return type. Does that mean the method `append` actually overloads on return type?

Answer (score 1):

When you invoke `c.getMethods()` the resulting array will contain all the methods, that are defined in the `StringBuilder` class and it superclass(es)/superinterface(s).

That's why you get three instead of one.

> Does that mean the method `append` actually overloads on return type?

No. Overloading is a term that is strongly related to the *method signature* definition. The method signature **includes**:

- the method name
- the method parameters

Overloading specifies two or more methods with the name, but different method signature. The return-type is not part of the method signature.

In your example, the three method definitions **are not overloaded**, but overridden versions of one and the same method abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

From [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethods()) we have :

> Returns an array containing Method objects reflecting all the public
>   member methods of the class or interface represented by this Class
>   object, ***including those declared by the class or interface and those
>   inherited from superclasses and superinterfaces.*** Array classes return
>   all the (public) member methods inherited from the Object class. The
>   elements in the array returned are not sorted and are not in any
>   particular order. This method returns an array of length 0 if this
>   Class object represents a class or interface that has no public member
>   methods, or if this Class object represents a primitive type or void.

```
 StringBuilder extends AbstractStringBuilder 

 AbstractStringBuilder implements Appendable
```

That's why you get 3 methods.